# How to wait for and read all data available from a Indy TCP socket?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I write a Indy TCP server / client application to transfer files. It seems that every call to a read or write operation on a TCP socket, in Indy, slows the transfer speed... I thinked a protocol with only a write and a read (replay). But, in this way, I cannot send the length of the buffer. So, I need to read all available data from the other side, in a continuously buffer. And this operation should wait first, if no data available. Is this possible ? I think it's something with the `ReadFromSource` method, but this is not documented in the help, and I don't know where it puts the readed data.
My protocol is made in a `TIdIOHandlerStack` descendant, so I can access protected IOHandler methods.

Edit: It seems that `ReadFromSource` gets only 32 KB in on shoot. I updated the `RecvBufferSize` to 2.1MB and when I send 2MB I get about 200 KB... :(

Update: This is the code I use to read all data from the source. Sometimes it works, but other times doesn't read the whole data...

```
function TIdEnhancedIOHandler.ReadAllBytes(var VBuffer: TIdBytes): Integer;
var LBytes, TmOut: Integer;
begin
 Result:= 0;
 Assert(FInputBuffer <> nil);
 if FInputBuffer.Size = 0 then TmOut:= -1 else TmOut:= 0;
 repeat
  LBytes:= ReadFromSource(False, TmOut, False);
  CheckForDisconnect(True, True);
  TmOut:= 0;
 until LBytes <= 0;
 Result:= FInputBuffer.Size;
 FInputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(VBuffer, -1, False);
end;
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you are having trouble with.  TCP is a byte stream, there is no 1-to-1 relation between writes and reads, and no concept of messages/files.  You must delimit your messages in your protocol, either by sending the message length (ie, the file size), or by sending a unique terminator after each message.  Indy has methods for writing/reading files/streams, why are you not using them?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, because I cannot show the file progress with Indy methods for streams. I cannot show now a code example because my brain doesn't work anymore... I've been struggling for about 6 hours with this problem... Maybe tomorow. But I just want to get all data available on the source and return. And if ti's not, wait until  at least one byte is sent.

Comment: "*because I cannot show the file progress with Indy methods for streams*" - yes, you can, via the `OnWork...` events. "*I've been struggling for about 6 hours with this problem*" - all the more reason to show the code you are struggling with. You are likely using it wrong. "*But I just want to get all data available on the source and return*" - that is not what you should do in this situation. But whatever. You can use the `ReadBytes()` method for that purpose, just set its `AByteCount` param to -1. "*wait until at least one byte is sent*" - Indy already handles such waiting for you by default

Comment: @RemyLebeau Check the code in the update... It doesn't return the whole data sometimes...

Comment: TCP connections are just a stream of bytes. The receiver has no way to know how much bytes a sender has or will send. The only thing the receiver know is when the sender closed the connection. So to send a given content (file, record, string), the sender must first send the length of the content and then the content itself. The receiver will first receive the length and then know how much data it has to receive. An alternative is to use a delimiter after the data. But in that case, obviously, the delimiter can't be included in the data and this is annoying when sending arbitrary data.

Comment: If you want to display a progress bar, pay attention that display can be very slow compared to the stream speed. You should NOT update your progress bar more often than one second (more or less).

Comment: Could be interesting for you to read http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/FAQ.Difference to understand how TCP protocol works.

Comment: @fpiette The sender sends only a block of data, and then waits for a replay. The receiver can read the socket until there is nothing to read (`ReadFromSource` returns -1). Check my code above. In some situations (when I use the debuger) that function works as it should, but it's not stable, and sometimes fails.

Comment: IMO this is bad design. OK to send by block, but the first byte(s) of a block should be the block length. On a LAN it may be useless, but on a WAN or anything with slow device in between, you may have the second block arrive at the same time as the first. To avoid that you have to ACK each block which will really slow down the process.

Comment: @fpiette If I don't acknowledge each block how can I know what's happens on the other side, if the data has arrived and was successfully written to the disk ? And I need and ACK to start reading the next block of data from disk... If I keep sending, and the receiver got stuck, I will fill the entire memory of the computer with that data... // If I send a byte with the block length, the receiver will have to do 2 read operation... this will not slow down the speed ?

Comment: You know data arrived without error because you did not receive an error. TCP is by design a reliable protocol: you either receive all data correctly or receive an error message. Of course you must check (and the library you use) for all error return and exceptions. TCP already acknowledge all packets, has checksum, retransmission in case of error, etc.  If the receiver has an issue writing data to disk, only then send an error message to the remote side. Send a positive acknowledge only when all data has been received and correctly saved on disk.

Comment: With TCP, sender will not fill memory with data. At some point, when enough data has been sent without acknowledge (not from application but from TCP/IP stack), then sender will stop sending.

Comment: There is definitely no need to read the length before the data. You can always read everything that is available and extract the length from what you have read. And note that you may read a partial length! Did you read the link I provided and explaining - in short - how TCP works?

Comment: @fpiette Yes, I read it. Thanks for the information you provided to me. That was really helpful ! Especially knowing that writing to the send buffer is blocked if it reach some level and the receiver does not read the data...